# In Lord of the Rings, why did hobbits appear to be more resilient to the Ring than men?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

Why can Bilbo, Frodo and to some extent Gollum resist the Ring's influence to a greater extent than men? What is the significance of this?

Comment: Asking why an author may a basic decision about the universe is pointless in the extreme. They wanted to tell a story. Full stop. Had they made a different assumption you'd have gotten a different story.

Comment: Frodo repeatedly put on the Ring, even after being explicitly told not to by Gandalf and of course he succumbed to its power at Mount Doom. Therefore I would not say he resisted the Ring's influence.

Comment: I don't think they can, why then didn't Frodo want to give up the ring and cast it into the Fire of Doom? The ring only has a different influence on the Hobbits, because they are different in nature, as all the other creatures are different in their nature.

Comment: @Secko - You are ignoring the circumstances surrounding Frodo's actions in Mount Doom.  He had been carrying the Ring for a year, and only at the last possible second did he succumb to it.  Contrast this with Boromir, who succumbed to the Ring within a couple of weeks, and within seconds of being alone with Frodo for the first time.  Frodo held up pretty well, considering how long he was a Ringbearer.

Comment: @WadCheber Dude, I wrote this two years ago. I'm much older and wiser now. Besides, I don't get your point. Aren't we saying the same thing?

Comment: @TheMathemagician That's ignoring context though. In the 17 years before he sets out he did quite well there. And he put the Ring on twice in the Fellowship to escape. Tolkien also notes that it's all but expected Frodo wouldn't be able to finish the quest on his own. But meanwhile he is very resilient to the Morgul-knife isn't he? That's also the power of Sauron. So yes actually he resisted the influence quite a lot. Your statement is trying to make it black and white. It's not.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Looking at this from the aspect of your comment (“why did Tolkien choose to create hobbits without these character traits?”) on [@Andomar’s answer (which actually includes evidence from the books — reward it with upvotes, readers)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36406/in-lord-of-the-rings-why-did-hobbits-appear-to-be-more-resilient-to-the-ring-th/#answer-36409), one of the themes of Lord of the Rings is the idea that the smallest, humblest person can change the destiny of the world, and become a hero.

The Hobbits represent small, humble, ordinary people. They don’t lust for power or fame, or aspire to do great deeds. Thus the Ring can’t corrupt them in the way that it would corrupt Boromir or Galadriel, although it can make them covet it as a possession.

This might have been inspired by Tolkien’s experiences in the First World War. The folk with grand ambitions and a lust for power seek terrible weapons to dominate the world, and the ordinary folk are forced to go to war and suffer as a consequence. To quote [Harry Patch, and/or Radiohead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Patch_(In_Memory_Of)):

> Give your leaders each a gun and then let them fight it out themselves

Comment: @TGnat: phew, cheers for the correction, I thought I might have got my wars mixed up.

Comment: @Secko: aw, cheers!

Comment: It's possible that I'm confusing this with a similar situation in the Dragonlance books, but weren't the Hobbits also designated as a "younger race" and therefore lacked some of the weaknesses of the earlier ones?

Comment: @SeanDuggan: possibly, although [this Wikia page](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Hobbits) suggests that their origins are ancient enough to be obscure.

Comment: For Bilbo and Frodo, it might also be worth noting that the manner of acquiring the ring was significant in the nature of its influence. I think it is specifically mentioned by Gandalf that if Bilbo had killed Gollum when he had the chance the ring's negative influence would have been greater (starting with pity not only saved the world [as Gollum was needed to destroy the ring] but saved Bilbo).

Comment: @WadCheber: if I see an opportunity to use a war veteran in order to gain points on a website, I grab it.

Answer (score 20):

Dwarves were even [more resistant to rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rings_of_Power).  Sauron couldn't control dwarves who wore a Great Ring.  The Dwarf's life was not extended, and he did not become invisible. From *The Silmarillion*:

> Seven rings he gave to the Dwarves; ... The Dwarves indeed proved tough and hard to tame; they ill endure the domination of others, and the thoughts of their hearts are hard to fathom, nor can they be turned to shadows.

All a ring did was amplify the Dwarf's bad character traits, like lust of gold.

While a Hobbit's life could be extended, a Hobbit (and especially Bilbo and Frodo) does not have many bad character traits that the Ring could work with.  But the Ring overcame Frodo in the end:

> 'I have come,' he said. 'But I do not choose now to do what I came to
>   do. I will not do this deed. The Ring is mine!'  And suddenly, as he set
>   it on his finger, he vanished from Sam's sight.

A Dwarf would not have been overcome like that.  But Dwarves are not very good at sneaking.  That's why Thorin was looking for a Hobbit in the first place :)

Comment: Don't think you can conclude that just because the 'Seven' rings that were given to the Dwarves didn't grant invisibility or long life that Dwarves were resistant to all rings especially the 'One'.  How do we know if Sauron didn't just simply create the 'Seven' without those characteristics ?  Can you provide additional citations to support the 'dwarf resistant to rings' premise ?

Comment: @Stan: From Wikipedia "the Dwarves' rings did not respond to the One's control as Sauron expected".  From The Silmarillion: "Seven rings he gave to the Dwarves; ... The Dwarves indeed proved tough and hard to tame; they ill endure the domination of others, and the thoughts of their hearts are hard to fathom, nor can they be turned to shadows."

Comment: Well, Sauron didn't try giving rings to Hobbits (mainly because he wasn't aware they existed), so I guess we'll never know :)

Comment: Hobbit rings of power would be doughnuts.

Comment: @Stan - If you're curious about whether Tolkien actually said that Dwarves were more resistant to the Ring, you should ask it as a separate question.  I can assure you that Tolkien **did** say this, and on more than one occasion.  He wrote that the only impact the Rings had on Dwarves was to increase their preexisting tendencies towards greed for jewels and precious metals.

Comment: @johntait.org - Because it makes the point that the least impressive people can be the greatest heroes.  Also, the Shire is an analogy for rural England before WWI, and the hobbits were an analogy for pre-war English people.

Comment: @Stan Quite simple. **Sauron didn't create any Ring but the One Ring!** Only in earlier drafts did he do that. So your argument doesn't hold. Just because he gave them to the Dwarves doesn't mean he made them. See Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age in The Silmarillion for fuller details. This is something the film got very wrong (in fact they're meant to be gold but the film has them in silver). Dwarf resistance is also mentioned there too btw.